# addslashes not working for $_GET single quotes

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping

I'm having issues with apostrophes in GET arrays. I can't seem to escape single quotes. I've trawled through similar SO topics for over a day now with no luck. I think this may be something to do with my connection to the database as if I make a plain unconnected php page both addslashes and str_replace successfully escape single quotes in GET variables (mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't since there is no database connection).

PHP 5.2.17
Mysql 5.5.23
Magic_quotes is off

The connection:

```
DEFINE ('database', 'dbname');
DEFINE ('user', 'dbusername');
DEFINE ('pass', 'dbpassword');
DEFINE ('host', 'localhost');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect (host, user, pass, database) OR die ('Could not connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
```

The database appears to be connected, select queries involving GET variables that do not have single quotes in work fine. However, now when a GET containing a single quote is passed, I can't seem to escape it.

```
print_r($_GET);
echo "<br><br>";

$text = "O'Reilly";

echo "Normal variable called text: " . $text . "<br>
addslashes(): " . addslashes($text) . "<br>
mysqli_real_escape_string(): " . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $text) . "<br>
str_replace(): " . str_replace("'", "\'", $text) . "<br>
<br>";

echo "_GET variable: " . $_GET['breed'] . "<br>
addslashes(): " . addslashes($_GET['breed']) . "<br>
mysqli_real_escape_string(): " . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['breed']) . "<br>
str_replace(): " . str_replace("'", "\'", $_GET['breed']) . "<br>
<br>";

$_GET['breed'] = "O'Conner";

echo "_GET variable with new value: " . $_GET['breed'] . "<br>
addslashes(): " . addslashes($_GET['breed']) . "<br>
mysqli_real_escape_string(): " . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['breed']) . "<br>
str_replace(): " . str_replace("'", "\'", $_GET['breed']) . "<br>
<br>";
```

gives:

```
Array ( [breed] => Cirneco dell'Etna )

Normal variable called text: O'Reilly
addslashes(): O\'Reilly
mysqli_real_escape_string(): O\'Reilly
str_replace(): O\'Reilly

_GET variable: Cirneco dell'Etna
addslashes(): Cirneco dell'Etna
mysqli_real_escape_string(): Cirneco dell'Etna
str_replace(): Cirneco dell'Etna

_GET variable with new value: O'Conner
addslashes(): O\'Conner
mysqli_real_escape_string(): O\'Conner
str_replace(): O\'Conner
```

The single quote in Cirneco dell'Etna is definitely a single quote, not ` etc. I also tried urlencode() and urldecode() - it replaced spaces with + but did not escape the single quotes. The GETs need single quotes to make user-friendly URLs - usernames and (in this case) breed names for example; Cirneco dell%39Etna is not intuitive. It's not a complex site at all but single quotes crop up a lot as ownership is a major part of the site, so I'd like to work out what's happening!

I have tried switching to PDO but found it beyond me - I'm a novice programmer and my attempt at PDO was mind-boggling to troubleshoot - I can't tell whether errors in PDO are my typos, or a continuation of this same issue.

Many thanks.

EDIT
The select query (which works as expected for _GET variables without single quotes in) is constructed as follows:

```
$q = "SELECT breed_name, breed_type from b_breed 
where breed_name = '" . $_GET['breed'] . "' 
LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

if($result->num_rows == 0)
    { 
    }
else
    { 
    $row_breed = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        {
        echo "<h1>" . $row_breed['breed_name'] . " - " . $row_breed['breed_type'] . "</h1>";
        }
    }
```

I have tried including addslashes, mysqli_real_escape_string and str_replace (not at the same time) with the $_GET within the query, to no effect. If I echo $q, the single quote is never escaped.

SELECT breed_name, breed_type from b_breed where breed_name = 'Cirneco dell'Etna' LIMIT 1

Oddly, if I switch the double and single quotes so I have:

```
$q = 'SELECT breed_name, breed_type from b_breed 
where breed_name = "' . $_GET['breed'] . '" 
LIMIT 1';
```

SELECT breed_name, breed_type from b_breed where breed_name = "Cirneco dell'Etna" LIMIT 1

It still returns no rows on the page, although the echoed $q will return rows in PHPMyAdmin.

EDIT Solved!

It was changing the ' in the database to an ASCII character. Adding the following converted it back to ', which could then be escaped:

```
$_GET['breed'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($_GET['breed'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Maybe single quote is passed like `%27`, although `$_GET` should auto decode. `%39` is not single quote.

Comment: how are you actually inserting/selecting to/from the db? You should not be using both `addslashes` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Only use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Ah whoops, I just grabbed %39 off an ASCII list. If I manually change the url to %27 instead of ' it instantly corrects itself back to ' in the address bar (Firefox) and still fails to escape the single quote on the page.

Comment: I just tested and works without a problem, maybe it's not really `'` ...

Comment: @CrayonViolent - I've added the Select queries to the post - I don't use them at the same time, I've just run through them to see if any work.

Comment: @MihaiIorga I'm sure it is - it's the same character used in O'Reilly - I've tried re-writing it (updating via PHPMyAdmin). Charset for database etc. is UTF-8.

Comment: Nothing is changed in database. Especially when no database involved at all (as with $_GET array). It is some your own code. You need to find that code and get rid of it, instead of adding useless decoding after useless encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what are You getting from GET

try

```
$string = $_GET['breed'];
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
    echo '<br>'.$string[$i].' : '.ord($string[$i]);
}
```

Comment: The ' is coming through as &#039...
`& : 38
# : 35
0 : 48
3 : 51
9 : 57
; : 59`
EDIT - when I run the same code on my page that isn't connected to the database (on which single quotes are successfully escaped), ' comes through simply as 39. So it does look like the connection is involved.

Comment: @user2025235: It's not literally a `'` character, it's being sent as `&#039;`.  Which is its ASCII code.  You can try to run `htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: Solved! Adding `$_GET['breed'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($_GET['breed'], ENT_QUOTES);` lets me then escape it - I am assuming it's related to my UTF8 charset converting the ' to ASCII code - either way, it now functions. Thank you both!